# pass functions as arguments

Tags: c#

i want to send the return result from the function to another function that collect them and later on print them here is waht i try:

```
 public void CreateAccount()
    {
        AccountList.Add(name(), code());
    }

    public string Name()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("insert your name : ");
        string name = Console.ReadLine();
        return name;
    }

    public int Code()
    {
        Random rnd4 = new Random();
        int fourNumbers = rnd4.Next(1000, 10000);
        return fourNumbers;

    }
```

i want to add to the list "name"+"code". what am i missing?

Comment: What's the problem? Does an error occur?

Comment: This is a perfectly good question except that it's missing some important information (namely, what AccountList is).  It was downvoted because a couple of people didn't consider that you're a beginner and, as such, they should help you improve your question (as JW was trying to do) rather than downvote it as if you knew what was wrong.  But don't worry, not everyone on SO are lazy like them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
AccountList.Add(Name());
AccountList.Add(Code());
```

I'd suggest renaming `Name()` and `Code()` to something like `PromptName()` and `PromptCode()` so their intent is more clear.

Comment: Wish I could +2 for also suggesting a better naming convention. =)

Comment: @J.Steen. I like your intent in making SO even better:-)

Answer (score 4):

You can add only one element to a list at a time using the `Add` method.

You probably want

```
accountList.Add(Name())
accountList.Add(Code());
```

And I hope `accountList` is a `List<object>` as you are adding strings and ints to the same list.